# powershell how to close a .exe process

Tags: powershell

I want to start a .exe file from powershell and wait for it to finish and then continue to the next line in the powershell. However after the .exe file finished it's job the window remain there to be manually closed. Just like notepad. Here is what I got

```
start-process -FilePath notepad -Wait -NoNewWindow
echo "it's done!"
```

I specified -NoNewWindow but it still comes with a window and the powershell have to wait until I manually close it. How can I close it automatically? The .exe file is a third party app that I have no control over.

Please note that I want to wait for the task that the .exe file completes and then automatically close that window so that I can continue to the next line in powershell.

I also tried -WindowStyle hidden.

```
start-process -FilePath notepad -Wait -WindowStyle hidden
echo "it's done!"
```

But this is even worse I have to go to task manager to kill the hidden window without knowing it is completed or not.

Is there a parameter better than -NoNewWindow that can force no new window show up?

Thanks,

Comment: To do this you either would have to `sleep` for a few seconds and assume the exe finished, or you would need some signal from the exe that the job was done. Does the exe do anything that would indicate its task is complete?  Create a file maybe?

Comment: the exe app launches a script window and writes a bunch of lines to the scripts window. at the end it will write "Finished" in the script window. That's how I know it's done. But when it's done the scripts window stays there and does not close automatically.

Comment: What does the exe/script window do? Is there anything you can verify from PS?

Comment: the exe imports data into database and then writes log to the script window the powershell has no way to get info from it. the exe is COM type of thing.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you can query the DB in powershell to see when the data is all there? Is there anyway you could get access to the output from the script window?  In a file?  Or by changing the scripts that the exe is calling?

Comment: How does the exe close?  Is it one of those "Press ENTER to Continue" things?

Comment: The exe has a menu. under file menu you can choose "Save scripts as" and "Exit Application", etc. or you can just press X window button on the title bar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88743/discussion-between-shawn-and-xdhmoore).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script below will:

1. Open Notepad.
2. Wait for you to type "Finished".
3. Close Notepad.

You will need to install [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/). (I selected "x86" in the installer BTW.)

You will also need to adapt the `Get-AU3ControlHandle` call to suit your needs. The AutoIt Window Info Tool will be useful there. You may have to do some reading of the AutoIt documentation.

See also [AutoIt Cmdlets for Windows PowerShell](https://www.autoitconsulting.com/site/scripting/autoit-cmdlets-for-windows-powershell/).

```
import-module "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX.psd1"
$p = Start-Process notepad -PassThru

# Wait for the window to open
while($p.MainWindowHandle -eq 0)
{
    Start-Sleep 1
}

$c = Get-AU3ControlHandle -WinHandle $p.MainWindowHandle -Control "Edit1"

while($true)
{
    $t = Get-AU3ControlText $p.MainWindowHandle $c

    if ($p.HasExited)
    {
        break;
    }
    elseif ($t -eq "Finished")
    {
        $p.CloseMainWindow();
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Waiting 1 sec."
        Start-Sleep 1
    }
}

Write-Output "Done"
```

Comment: Dan, I tried the it works if I type Finish in the first line. If I typed several lines and then the last line contains Finish it won't catch it. The script window has thousands of lines written and the last line is *Finished*. And it 's not be key stroke. Is there a way for me to catch it? Thanks

Comment: @Shawn, the variable $t contains all of the text from the control. So instead of `$t -eq "Finished"`, you could do something like `$t.Contains("Finished")` or `$t.EndsWith("Finished")` or `$t -match 'Finished'` or whatever. Basically you will have to understand the code I have written and adapt it to your needs because I am unfamiliar with your particular program, so I don't know the details. You need to (1) Find the right control to look for in the `Get-AU3ControlHandle` call. (2) After retrieving the text from the control, look for "Finished" in it.

Comment: @Shawn, it might be a good idea to increase the 1-second polling delay (`Start-Sleep 1`) to something bigger, otherwise the script could be needlessly using up too much CPU since it is retrieving thousands of lines of text each time through the loop.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use to kill iTunes automatically. But, as mentioned in my comment, if you want to wait for it to be done, you'd have to add either a `sleep` or do some application-specific check to see that its job is done.  What that check is depends on what the exe is doing.

```
$itunesProc = Get-Process -name iTunes -ErrorAction "Ignore"
if ($itunesProc -ne $null) {
   echo "Stopping iTunes..."
   Stop-Process -Name iTunes
} else {
   echo "No running iTunes process found"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There may be multiple processes of that exe. some of which are not started by my powershell. If I just get by name I could not identify which one is spawned by my powershell.

Comment: I was thinking you would just get the name of the exe, and that would kill everything else. But i'm not sure.